# How clear all Pushpin on Map on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, maps, pushpin

I want to clear all a `Pushpin` on Map. I can use `map.Children.Clear()`, it's work good. But I work with `google maps` and use this XAML code:

```
<my:Map Height="756" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="googlemap"
                   CredentialsProvider="AqayajnZU8FSfDGL8jpK5zMKAHmUL27Uqxv_OnpQzJQOI2PoQyxcG7dlR6_g4WWo" 
                   CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" 
                   ScaleVisibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" >
                <my:Map.Mode>
                    <MSPCMCore:MercatorMode/>
                </my:Map.Mode>
                <my:MapTileLayer Name="street" Margin="0,0,0,32" Height="800" Width="433">
                    <my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
                        <GoogleTileSource:GoogleTile TileTypes="Street"/>
                    </my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
                </my:MapTileLayer>
            </my:Map>
```

So, when I call `map.Children.Clear()` then `MapTileLayer` removed too. How I can remove only `Pushpin`?

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all the children and remove only the ones that are of type Pushpin

```
foreach (var item in googlemap.Children.ToList())
{
    if (item is MapTileLayer) continue;
    googlemap.Children.Remove(item);
 }
```